# Address location in integer form back to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to figure out if its possible to take the integer address of an integer in memory, and cast it back to an actual pointer. Below is an example. My eventual goal, and maybe im overcomplicating the problem is I have a pointer to a very large object in memory. I need to share the pointer/data to other threads and the only mechanism I have in place (legacy system) is to communicate with uint8_t[8] arrays. So I was going to take the pointer address, convert it to an int, split it into a byte array, transmit, and re-assemble it on the other end.

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
  /* Test value to see if code works */
  uint64_t value = 123;
  /* Get the pointer to the value, this is what we will working with */
  uint64_t* value_ptr = &value;
  /* Get the integer value of the address/memory location, this is what I am 
    try to cast back into a pointer to 'value' */
  uint64_t value_adr_int = &value_ptr;
  /* Some time later we want to get back to value_ptr. 
    This is the piece not working */
  uint64_t* cast_value_ptr = (uint64_t*)value_adr_int;
  /* Test to make sure our newly casted pointer points to the original int */
  if (*cast_value_ptr == value) {
    /* Print success */
  }
  
}
```

Edit: Answer thanks to Daniel was changing the one line to:

```
uintptr_t value_adr_int = (uintptr_t)value_ptr;
```

Comment: And what happens? BTW you don't have an int, you have a bunch of uint64_t.

Comment: @jarmod correct I have uint64's to represent an 8 byte array and pointer size, so my bad. As for for what happens, I get *cast_value_ptr to be the address location in integer form.

Comment: On a side note (just in case you're not already aware), make sure you account for Endianness when converting to and from the `uint8_t` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `value_adr_int` to `&value_ptr`.  That would mean that `value_adr_int` holds the value of a `uint64_t**` instead of a `uint64_t*` which is what you want.  You need to remove the `&`.

On another note, you should use `uintptr_t`, which was added (I believe) in C99.  It is an integer type designed for this exact situation.  It is perfectly safe to cast pointers to `uintptr_t` and back.

Comment: wow that solved it. However I do get a compiler warning, any proper way to avoid this "warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') with an expression of type 'uint64_t *' (aka 'unsigned long long *'); dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]'

Comment: On which line are you getting this?

Comment: On the new updated line 'uint64_t value_adr_int = value_ptr;'

Comment: `value_adr_int` should be a `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Changed that as well, still same compiler warning. Forcing the cast with (uintptr_t)value_ptr solved it. Will mark as answer when timer allows me

Comment: Huh.  I'm getting that too.  I would have thought the compiler would figure that out.  Oh, well.